# How to add a colored background which looks like an underline BENEATH the text in a sentence in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, flutter-layout

The first word is underlined but if you look closely, the text overlaps a part of the colored shape/part. It is not just under the text.

**Here is what I am trying to achieve:**

[image: Sample image]

**Here's my current code:**

```
                text: TextSpan(children: <TextSpan>[
                  TextSpan(
                    text: "Welcome",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: HSColors.darkBlue,
                        decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                        decorationColor: HSColors.cream,
                        decorationThickness: 5.h,
                        fontSize: 30.sp,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                        height: 1.1,
                        letterSpacing: -0.03),
                  ),
                  TextSpan(
                    text: " to Veritas Monitoring Services",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: HSColors.darkBlue,
                        fontSize: 30.sp,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                        height: 1.1,
                        letterSpacing: -0.03),
                  )
                ]),
              ),
```

**Here is what it currently looks like:**

[image: Here is the output]

**Moreover, if I use other text, it overlaps and looks like this:**

[image: Overlap]

Comment: What does mean by half colored background?

Comment: @MuhammadNoman Sorry if I could not phrase it properly but the idea is that the colored line under the text is overlapped by the text at some point, not just under the text vertically.

Comment: You can use Stack for this. Should I show an example?

Comment: @MuhammadNoman I would appreciate an example. Thank you.

Comment: I have just put an example below in answers, do check it. Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

You need to work with decorationThickness value.

```
decorationThickness: 5.h,
```

I have lower the decorationThickness value to

```
decorationThickness: 0.2.h,
```

Here's the result on iPhone 12 simulator

[image]

Comment: Check the image I am trying to achieve. The idea is that the colored line under the text is overlapped by the text partially, not just under the text vertically. In your sample, the underline is not overlapped by the text at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive this using Stack as shown below. Set the behind container's height and width as per your need. Thanks

```
Stack(
    alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
    children: [
        Container(
            height: 15,
            width: 130,
            color: Colors.amber,
        ),
        Text("Welcome",
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 30,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                height: 1.1,
                letterSpacing: -0.03),
        ),
    ],
),
```

[image]